# Does Unity iOS build process have a signature?

Tags: unity, ios, xcode

I'm interested in the detailed process that happens when Unity Editor builds iOS at this step:

*- Xcode project is generated by Unity with all the required libraries, precompiled .NET code, and serialized assets - https://docs.unity.cn/Manual/iphone-BuildProcess.html*

**Questions:**

1. Does Unity somehow sign an Xcode-generated project?
2. Is it possible to determine that a particular build of Xcode was made on a particular Mac device?
3. If there is a signature - Is it possible to manually change the signature after generating the Xcode project?

Comment: If there was a signature and it would be trival to change it, that would defeat the point of having a signature. The points 2) and 3) read a bit like an XY problem, what do you want to achieve/ prevent?

Comment: @Zibelas We study the issue of security and copyright in our company. I would like to understand whether any signing occurs at the time of generating the Xcode project, for example, with a key or certificate located on the Mac device by default or something else.

Comment: As far as I know, before you can publish an app (either android or apple), the app is going to be signed by a certificate. for example before your app can integrate app services, be installed on a device, or be submitted to the App Store, it must be signed with a certificate issued by Apple. The certificate is the key, safeguard the process of signing